# NHibernate Bag Mapping

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, mapping

I need a hand mapping a collection.

I am using a join table to hold references to rooms ids and calEvent Ids.
However, the look ups will mainly be based on the room's `buildingID` - so I'd like to add `buildingID` to the following mapping. Does anyone know how to do so?

I've looked through the NHibernate docs but can't find anything.

```
<bag name="rooms" table="tb_calEvent_rooms" lazy="false">
  <key column="calEventID"/>
  <many-to-many class="BasicRoom" column="roomID"/>
</bag>
```

Class:

```
public class BasicRoom 
{
    private long _id;
    private long _buildingID;
    private string _roomName;
```

Any hints/help much appreciated.

**Reasoning:**

A room will never change building so if I add buildingID to the join table;
I will reduce the complexity of the select statement from something like -

```
SELECT *
FROM
  dbo.tb_calEvent_rooms
  INNER JOIN dbo.tb_calEvents ON (dbo.tb_calEvent_rooms.calEventID = dbo.tb_calEvents.id)
  INNER JOIN dbo.tb_rooms ON (dbo.tb_calEvent_rooms.roomID = dbo.tb_rooms.id)
  INNER JOIN dbo.tb_buildings ON (dbo.tb_rooms.buildingID = dbo.tb_buildings.id)
WHERE
  dbo.tb_buildings.id = 54
```

To

```
SELECT *
FROM
  dbo.tb_calEvents
  INNER JOIN dbo.tb_calEvent_rooms ON (dbo.tb_calEvents.id = dbo.tb_calEvent_rooms.calEventID),
  dbo.tb_buildings
WHERE
  dbo.tb_buildings.id = 54
```

Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `column` attribute from the `many-to-many` element and add it as a child node insead, alongside an additional `column` element referencing the `buildingID`:

```
<bag name="rooms" table="tb_calEvent_rooms" lazy="false">
  <key column="calEventID"/>
  <many-to-many class="BasicRoom">
    <column name="roomID"/>
    <column name="buildingID"/>
  </many-to-many>
</bag>
```

That should enable you to query based on the `buildingID` as well as `roomID`.

Comment: Thanks for this,
I'm getting the following error though.

faultString = "Foreign key (FK3EDE57A96B977B0C:tb_calEvent_rooms [roomID, buildingID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (tb_rooms [id])"
I suppose the room or building mapping is incorrect. Hmmmmm..

Comment: Yes, you will need to include both columns as PK in the referenced table.